# How do you get the photo name of a picture in drawable?

Tags: java, android, xml

How do you get the photo name of a picture in drawable? For instance if the photo was test.jpg then I want to get the name "test" from my image viewer.

```
ImageView picture = new ImageView(this);
picture.setImageResource(R.id.test);
String hello = picture.getResource.name?
```

Any help would be appreciate thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageView doesn't keep track of that, but you could extend ImageView and do it yourself. (Using the code from chessdork). Override the setImageResource method.

```
public class MyImageView extends ImageView {
    private String imageName;

    @Override
    public void setImageResource(int resourceId) {
       imageName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(resourceId);
       super.setImageResource(resourceId);
    }

    public String getImageName() {
       return imageName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.id.test)` should do the trick.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceEntryName(int)

Comment: Ah I see. The problem is that I want to get the actual title FROM the imageviewer as the image changes and i want to be able to tell what photo is in the imageviewer